# Canvas drawImage: Trying to crop and stretch

Tags: html, html5-canvas, crop, drawimage

I've tried a bunch of alternatives, and but each approach has not produced the desired result of stretching an image from a new `sx` to the end of the canvas.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the image shows what you want to happen, not what is actually happening. You can do all of this in the drawImage call. You don't typically see the parameters explained this way, but I think it will help for what you want to do.

```
ctx.drawImage(imgSrc, cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight, drawAtX, drawAtY, drawWidth, drawHeight);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yLf5erut/2/